# php lost curl handle reference

Tags: php, curl, request, php-curl

At the bottom of the code snippet, I am attempting to remove the curl handle from the multi handle. However PHP reports that it is an invalid curl handle. the curl_close call reports the same thing. I am confused since I have not closed it above that point.

Am i losing it anywhere. I don't see where...

```
    foreach ($urls as $url) {

        $request = [];
        $request['url'] = $url;
        $request['body'] = '';
        $request['response_headers'] = [];
        $request['curl_handle'] = curl_init();

        $url['config'] = json_decode($url['config'], true);

        if($url['config']['method'] == 'GET') {
            curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        }

        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_URL, $url['source_url']);

        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($curl, $body) use (&$request) {
            $request['body'] .= $body;
            return strlen($body);
        });
        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $header) use (&$request) {
            $request['response_headers'][] = $header;
            return strlen($header);
        });

        $followRedirects = boolval($url['config']['follow_redirects']);
        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $followRedirects);  

        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, intval($url['config']['total_redirects']));

        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS);

        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_MAXFILESIZE, intval($url['config']['max_download']));

        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);  
        curl_setopt($request['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  

        $requests[] = &$request;
    }

    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    //add the handles
    foreach ($requests as &$request) {
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $request['curl_handle']);
    }

    $active = null;
    //execute the handles
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        print('after exec');
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {            
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

        if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
                print('performing again');
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }

    if ($mrc != CURLM_OK) {
        print("Curl multi read error $mrc\n");
    }

    foreach ($requests as &$request) {
        processResponse($request);

        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $request['curl_handle']);
        curl_close($request['curl_handle']);
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: I rolled the question back. If the answer provided solved it, consider accepting it. If not and you came up with your own, you can post your own answer and accept it when Stack lets you. Accepting it marks it as "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that $request was being copied by reference into $requests, so the same curl_handle was being passed through multi curl and then to close_handle multiple times. The fix was not setting $request by reference into $requests.

I changed :

```
$requests[] = &$request;
```

to

```
$requests[] = $request;
```

That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change following lines:

```
foreach ($requests as &$request) {
        processResponse($request);

        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $request['curl_handle']);
        curl_close($request['curl_handle']);
    }
```

to

```
     foreach ($requests as &$request) {
            processResponse($request);

            curl_close($request['curl_handle']);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $request['curl_handle']);

        }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, however that won't work, as i have curl_getinfo calls in the processResponse function and they are failing as well alongside the remove and close calls afterwards...

Comment: do you get same error if you comment the  processResponse($request); call? You are passing $request by reference and we don't know what happens inside

Comment: yeah, just tried that, getting the same error, i just don't see where the curl handle becomes invalid